# Meu Drawer abre, mas não exibe as páginas, como exibir minhas páginas no Drawer navigator (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

estou utilizando o **React Navigation v4**. Criei um arquivo routes para redirecionar as minhas páginas. Porém estou com um problema: Criei um drawer navigator, e ele está sendo exibido, mas quando ele abre, ele só mostra a primeira tela, que no caso é "LagoaGuia" e a próximas páginas não aparecem. Como faço para poder corrigir este erro? O trecho do código é este abaixo:

```
const Routes = createAppContainer(
  createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      LagoaGuia: {
        screen: Menus,
      },
      Acougue: {
        screen: Acougue,
      },
    },
    {
      drawerBackgroundColor: "#222",
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iae, vou te dar um exemplo simples...

```
const FairScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
    MainScreen: {
        screen: FairScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            gesturesEnabled: false,
            header: (
                <Header
                    color="#ea7715"
                    openDrawer={() => {
                        navigation.openDrawer();
                    }}
                />
            ),
        }),
    },
});

const MapScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
    MainScreen: {
        screen: MapScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            gesturesEnabled: false,
            header: (
                <Header
                    color="#da0652"
                    openDrawer={() => {
                        navigation.openDrawer();
                    }}
                />
            ),
        }),
    },
});

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Fair: {
            screen: FairScreenStack,
        },
        Map: {
            screen: MapScreenStack,
        },
    },
    {
        contentComponent: menuSide,
        drawerWidth: 250,
        initialRouteName: 'Fair',
    }
);

export default DrawerNav;
```

Minha tela de menu é a seguinte...

```
class sideMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 170, marginBottom: 20 }}>
                <Button
                    title={'FEIRA'}
                    titleStyle={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
                    icon={
                        <Image source={require('../../assets/iconemenu.png')}
                            style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }} />
                    }
                    buttonStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        padding: 5,
                        paddingLeft: 10,
                        elevation: 0,
                    }}
                    containerStyle={style.sideMenu.menuItens}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Fair')}
                />
                <Button
                    title={'MAPA DA FEIRA'}
                    titleStyle={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
                    icon={
                        <Image source={require('../../assets/MapadaFeira.png')}
                            style={{ width: 16, height: 16 }} />
                    }
                    buttonStyle={{
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        padding: 5,
                        paddingLeft: 10,
                        elevation: 0,
                    }}
                    containerStyle={style.sideMenu.menuItens}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default sideMenu;
```