# Dispatch Drawer não funciona

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

estou tentanto implementar um drawer em meu app. Como eu quero somente em uma das minhas **screens**. Ao tentar implementar, eu senti algumas dificuldades. Então fiz passo a passo para não se perder.

Criei um botão e quero fazer o drawer **abrir** quando ele for **clicado**, porém não está me retornando nada.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import TabsNav from './TabsLeadScreen';

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Contact: {
        screen: TabsNav
    },
    Teste: {
        screen: TabsNav
    }
}, {});

const DrawerCustom = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

function ShowScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="abrir" onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} />
            <DrawerCustom />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Estou usando o

-react-navigation: **^4.0.10**

-expo: **~37.0.3**

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Iae, use esse link como exemplo.
Qualquer dúvida só comentar
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446384/160305](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446384/160305)

Comment: Opa, então, eu inserir um modelo igual o seu, porém quando eu dou um onclick no botão para abrir, ele continua não acontecendo nada... Ai inserir um console.log para ver o retorno dele, está retornando **false**  `estou passando esse código navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())`

Answer (score 0):

Se quer apenas em uma screen, cria um botão para abrir a Drawer.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home,},
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerContent,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#F05B66"
    },
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    drawerWidth: deviceWidth - 90,

  }
)
```

**_navigator.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())**

```
const Logado = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: Home,}, 
    Painel: {screen: Painel,},
    Drawer: {screen: Drawer}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: "none",
    lazy: true,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Então, quando eu tento fazer o onpress para dar o `DrawerActions.openDrawer())` ele não retorna nada, então inseri um console.log para ver que tipo de retorno está dando, o retorno dele é false... O que será que pode ser?